# add a class without jquery if hover another class

Tags: html, css

i've the following html structure

```
<div id="maindiv" class="cl_maindiv">
    <label>123</label>
    <span class="cl_span_icon"> :-)) </span>
    <div id"icon_content_div" class="cl_icon_content"> more happy faces :-))   </div>                              
</div>
```

For this i want, on hover THIS span with class "cl_span_icon" (pay attention, i have a lot of same content, and i only want, that this works for this, inside this div i'm hover the span), add the "cl_showme" class to the div id="icon_content_div"
.

So i try it with

```
.cl_maindiv>.cl_span_icon:hover .cl_showme{
  display:block;
}
```

What is the right way to do it?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Adding a class***, unfortunately, impossible with plain `CSS`.
To do this you **must** use `JavaScript`.

But, if you don't add a class, you can do it by **CSS pseudo-classes** (like `:hover`). This won't add the class, but your example can work with a little edit.

I think that you'll need something like this:

```css
.cl_maindiv>.cl_span_icon:not(:hover)+.cl_icon_content{
  /*Styles without :hover*/
  display:none;
}
.cl_maindiv>.cl_span_icon:hover+.cl_icon_content{
  /*Styles with :hover*/
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="maindiv" class="cl_maindiv">
    <label>123</label>
    <span class="cl_span_icon"> :-)) </span>
    <div id="icon_content_div" class="cl_icon_content"> more happy faces :-))</div>                              
</div>
```

Comment: maybe you missunderstoud me, i want not add a new class, i want to assign a existing class on hover to another element (another as that wich is on hover) i know that this is possible but i dont know how in this case

Comment: @RainerS Using *only* CSS you can't assign an existing class to an HTML element. This is possible by JS, but not ONLY by CSS.