# display a div blinking while another div is animated

Tags: html, css

Based on this question [add a class without jquery if hover another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54340445/add-a-class-without-jquery-if-hover-another-class)

I have a div which will display by hover of a span element. That works fine.

I have another div in the site which is animated with animate.css

If the div from above, is changed from `display:none` to `display:block`, the div is blinking/flutter.

(if I change the CSS by using jQuery, the div doesn't blink - what is the difference?)

In this snippet it works fine, I don't know why on my page it did not work?

```css
 .cl_maindiv>.cl_span_icon:not(:hover)+.cl_icon_content{
      /*Styles without :hover*/
      display:none;
    }
    .cl_maindiv>.cl_span_icon:hover+.cl_icon_content{
      /*Styles with :hover*/
      display:block;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 9px;
    top: 1px;
    margin: 0px;
    right: 14px;
    background-color: rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.90);
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(50, 197, 210, 0.90);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.25);
    min-width: 30px;
    color: #ddd;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #111;
    }
```

```html
<div id="maindiv" class="cl_maindiv" style="float:left;border:1px solid #ff0000;">
    <label>123</label>
    <span class="cl_span_icon"> :-)) </span>
    <div id="icon_content_div" class="cl_icon_content"> more happy faces :-))</div>                              
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.4u.tools/assets/plugins/animate.css-master/animate.min.css">
<div id="animdiv" class="animated pulse" style="animation-iteration-count: infinite; float:left;border:1px solid #ff0000;"> <h2>I'm a animated div!</h2></div>
```

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: You have not provided any code for us to look at to help diagnose, so we have no idea what you're currently doing. What have you tried, what's the expected result, what's the actual result. Take a read on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question. We'll be more than happy to help, but we can't guess because then we won't find an accurate solution.

Comment: you've right :-) Ive update my post and add a snippet, but in the snippet it works...:-(

Comment: is it possible to add your jquery code here?

Comment: If it's working as expected in the snippet, it sounds like you have a CSS situation on your page. Try creating a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) using your exact code and see if you can replicate the error there.

Comment: yes so it is, i've find the problem in css of another element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've find the answear in the css of another div beside of them.

Adding: overflow: hidden; solved that blinking ;-)

Thanks a lot!